# Why is my string getting repeatedly in this function?

Tags: javascript

I have this function that checks if a string has an accent and if it's length. It's working but i get my string repeatedly

[image]

It should be " **ateció** "

```
var accentArray = ["á","à","ã","â","é","è","ê","í","ì","î","õ","ó","ò","ô","ú","ù","û"]

function encrypt(str) {             
   let String = " ";   
   if (str.length <= 4)
   {
      for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++)  
      {           
         if (str[i] != "a" && str[i] != "e" && str[i] != "i" && str[i] != "o" && str[i] != "u")                                   
         {           
             String += str[i];         
         }   
       }  
   }
   else if(str.length >= 4)
   {
      for(var j=0; j < accentArray.length; j++)
      {
         for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++)  
         {           
            if (str[i] != "n")                                   
            {          
                String += str[i];         
            }
         }   
      }  
   }
   return String;   
}
console.log(encrypt('atención'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4Lbafhdv/

Comment: Why is it repeated? Because you repeat your operation `accentArray.length` times.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen how can i avoid to repeat it ? I need to check if the String has more than 4 words then check if it has an accent...

Comment: What is it supposed to do if it has an accent? I don't see you doing anything with your accentArray other than looping it.

Comment: @Seegy It's a encrypt function that detect if a word has an accent. If the word has an accent and has more than 4 words then the encrypt function do it's work, in this case as the word attentión (or atención in spanish) has more than 4 words and has an accent then it should remove the "N", the result must be ateció but i get atecióatecióatecióateció unlimited times.

Comment: Please rethink about the line `for(var j=0; j < accentArray.length; j++)` . Why did you wrap the things in this loop? You are not even using the `j` anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your `for(var j=0; j < accentArray.length; j++)` is meaningless. You
  are not using the `j` variable anywhere. You just make the inner
  codes run `accentArray.length` times. If you want to check if the
  string includes an accent, you could write

  `if ([...str].some(c => accentArray.includes(c)))`
- There is a better way to remove characters from a string: use
  [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- `String` is a built-in class name. Avoid using it as
  your own variable name.
- `if(str.length <= 4){}else(str.length >=4){}` is equivalent to `if(str.length <= 4){}else{}`
- `if..else..` statement which simply returns/sets a value in the body can be simplified with ternary operator.

```js
var accentArray = ["á", "à", "ã", "â", "é", "è", "ê", "í", "ì", "î", "õ", "ó", "ò", "ô", "ú", "ù", "û"]

function encrypt(str)
{
  return (str.length <= 4) ? str.replace(/[aeiou]/g,"") :
        [...str].some(c => accentArray.includes(c)) ? str.replace(/n/g,"") : "";
    
}
console.log(encrypt('atención'));
console.log(encrypt('aten'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping your `accentArray`, I used the javascript `includes` to check if the word an accent. If it has an accent, it will set the `hasAccent` variable to `true`. If the `hasAccent` variable is true, it will return the `String` otherwise it returns `false` or you can change it to what you need to return.

The reason the word was looping ateció constantly was because you are running the loop accentArray.length * str.length times.

Note that if your string has a length of 4, it is only in the <=4 condition because you are covering the length of 4 with <=4 and >=4

Also your String has a default space at the front. If this was unintended, please initialize your `String` variable to `let String = ""` or I would suggest using lowercase `let string = ""`

This solution will not work in ie. https://caniuse.com/?search=includes

```js
var accentArray = ["á","à","ã","â","é","è","ê","í","ì","î","õ","ó","ò","ô","ú","ù","û"]

function encrypt(str) {             
  let String = " ";   
  let hasAccent = false;
  if (str.length <= 4) {
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {           
      if (str[i] != "a" && str[i] != "e" && str[i] != "i" && str[i] != "o" && str[i] != "u") {
        String += str[i];         
      }   
    }  
  } else if(str.length >= 4) {
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if(accentArray.includes(str[i])) hasAccent = true;
      if (str[i] != "n") {
        String += str[i];         
      }
    }
  }
  return str.length >= 4 && hasAccent ? String : str.length <= 4 ? String : false; 
} 
console.log(encrypt('atención'));
console.log(encrypt('atencin'));
console.log(encrypt('ate'));
```